# Take the numbers that have 7 and write "boom" instead

Tags: excel, vba

I want at the end of the loop, he will show me all the numbers from a1 to a2 in a msg box but he will take the numbers that have 7 and will write "boom" instead,
What I need to do in the last part?

[image]

```
Private Sub booming_Click()

Dim a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer, s As Integer

a1 = VBA.InputBox("what's your first number?")
a2 = VBA.InputBox("what's your second number?")

If a1 < 10 Or a1 > 99 Or a2 < 10 Or a2 > 99 Then
    VBA.MsgBox "Invalid"
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = a1 To a2
If i Mod 10 = 7 Or (i Mod 100) \ 10 = 7 Then VBA.MsgBox "booming"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what do you need. It should: print every number from a1 to a2 and while this number contains 7 then pritn booming? for example: 13, 14, 15, 16, booming, 18, 19,, ...? Or it should print numbers in range (11, 12, 13, 14) when there is no 7, but if there is 7 then dont print numbers just booming? Or it should check if input contain 7 instead checking each nubmer in range?

Comment: the first option - : 13, 14, 15, 16, booming, 18, 19

Comment: for example if i a1 is 60 and a2 is 78 it will write me in msgbox - 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,boom,68...... till 78

Comment: What about 70, 71, 72, 73, ...? It all should be booming?

Comment: yeah every thing with 7

Comment: but i want all of them to be shown in the same msg box like that 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,boom,68...... till 78

Answer (score 0):

In case it should booming if any part of your number have 7 (so for 17, 27, ..., 67, 70, 71, 72, ..., 79, 87, 97) you just need to add "else" to your if:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub booming_Click()

Dim a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer, temp
Dim i As Integer, s As Integer

a1 = VBA.InputBox("what's your first number?")
a2 = VBA.InputBox("what's your second number?")

'OPTIONALLY FIX IF SECOND INPUT IS SMALLER THAN FIRST
If a1 > a2 Then
    temp = a1
    a1 = a2
    a2 = temp
End If



If a1 < 10 Or a1 > 99 Or a2 < 10 Or a2 > 99 Then
    VBA.MsgBox "Invalid"
    Exit Sub
End If


For i = a1 To a2
    If i Mod 10 = 7 Or (i Mod 100) \ 10 = 7 Then
        VBA.MsgBox "booming"
    Else
        VBA.MsgBox i
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Additionally, I've added some code which swaps your variables if the first is bigger.
You can instead, for example print some error in that case.
If you don't put anything for this case user wouldn't know what is happening because for loop will end instantely without anny message

## EDIT

Version which shows only 1 msgbox

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub booming_Click()

Dim a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer, temp
Dim i As Integer, s As Integer

a1 = VBA.InputBox("what's your first number?")
a2 = VBA.InputBox("what's your second number?")

'OPTIONALLY FIX IF SECOND INPUT IS SMALLER THAN FIRST
If a1 > a2 Then
    temp = a1
    a1 = a2
    a2 = temp
End If

Dim msg As String
msg = ""


If a1 < 10 Or a1 > 99 Or a2 < 10 Or a2 > 99 Then
    VBA.MsgBox "Invalid"
    Exit Sub
End If


For i = a1 To a2
    
    If i Mod 10 = 7 Or (i Mod 100) \ 10 = 7 Then
        If msg = "" Then
            msg = "booming"
        Else
            msg = msg & ",booming"
        End If
    Else
        If msg = "" Then
            msg = i
        Else
            msg = msg & "," & i
        End If
    End If
Next

VBA.MsgBox msg


End Sub
```